# Can ASP.NET OWIN be set to challenge users for a 2FA code at random/occasional intervals?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, owin

I'd like to configure my MVC application to randomly challenge users with a 2-factor authentication check on 1-in-N visits to the site.

To start with, I just did this as part of the login:

```
int challengeFrequency = Convert.ToInt16(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ChallengeFrequency"]);
var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: true);
switch (result)
{
    case SignInStatus.Success:
        Random rnd = new Random();
        if(rnd.Next(challengeFrequency) == 1)
        {
            if (!await SignInManager.SendTwoFactorCodeAsync("Phone Code"))
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Error");
            }
            return RedirectToAction("VerifyCode", new { Provider = "Phone Code", ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
        }
        return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
    // other cases
}
```

But it transpires I'd misunderstood the process, and that PasswordSignInAsync isn't called if the user has a valid cookie for the site. I was planning to change these settings so that users had to sign in every time in any case, so in Startup.Auth I added:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
    SlidingExpiration = true,
    ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5),
    Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
    {
        OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
            validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0), 
            regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
    }
});
```

So now users get challenged every time. But, of course, without a cookie, we never get a SignInStatus.Success result and the user is always challenged for both password and for a 2FA code.

How can I interrupt the process to ensure the user always has to sign in with a password, but is only occasionally asked for a 2FA code?

Comment: Nice solution, but perhaps you are better off with something slightly different? So asking on every 10th login, or being able to set a flag against the user that the next login must use 2FA. That way you get a bit more control and you are not left with a situation where the user potentially never needs 2FA verification (probability is fun like this!)

Comment: @DavidG Oh for sure - I was just looking for the bare-bones mechanic of where to stop the normal login process to facilitate what I want to do. The answer is to generate your own code, login directly with that and bypass sending it to the user. Now I've got that I can work out a more statistically interesting method of random sampling for myself :)

Comment: I quite like the idea of a flag on the user to force 2FA. That way if you get a security issue, you can update the database to force everyone to use 2FA on the next login. You could also have a process for forcing it when you detect too many invalid password attempts etc. OK, I'm getting too excited about this one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to to this eventually by generating a token on the fly and using it to fulfill the TwoFactorSignIn method, like so:

```
int challengeFrequency = Convert.ToInt16(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ChallengeFrequency"]);
var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: true);
switch (result)
{
    case SignInStatus.Success:
        return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
    case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
        Random rnd = new Random();
        if (rnd.Next(1, challengeFrequency) == 1)
        {
            if (!await SignInManager.SendTwoFactorCodeAsync("Phone Code"))
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
            }

            return RedirectToAction("VerifyCode", new { Provider = "Phone Code", ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
        }
        else
        {
            var token = await UserManager.GenerateTwoFactorTokenAsync(user.Id, "Phone Code");
            await SignInManager.TwoFactorSignInAsync("Phone Code", token, false, false);
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        }
    // other cases
}
```